# Laravel registration and login pages on a subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am creating a website in Laravel 5.3 that has two different entry points for registration, these entry points need to be subdomains.

I've setup the two routes but I am a bit lost how I would setup the Auth::routes() for the two subdomains.

One route will be for users who will register and pay a monthly subscription fee while the other route will not have a subscription fee attached to them.

As a site note: the two registration forms are identical at the moment but one could get a few more fields added than the basic username / password fields (think of name, surname, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sub-domain-feature in the routing component:

> Route groups may also be used to handle sub-domain routing. Sub-domains may be assigned route parameters just like route URIs, allowing you to capture a portion of the sub-domain for usage in your route or controller. The sub-domain may be specified using the domain key on the group attribute array:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        // your code
    });
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Answer (score 1):

If subscribed users and non subscribed users are in the same table you can manually authenticate users (see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users)):

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
  // The user is logged in
}
```

This `Auth:attempt` method has an option to send more parameters:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'subscribed' => 1])) {
    // The user is a subscriber and logged in
}
```

You would need an extra field in your database that shows if a user is subscribed or not (`subscribed`) for this, and you should fill this with 1 or 0 via the two different registration pages.

The `name` and `surname` fields should be `nullable` in your database so filling them is optional.